# Add an integer to all numbers in a file (shell)

Tags: file, shell, numbers, integer, addition

pretty silly question.

So basically I have a file like this

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 ... 1321
```

What I want is to add an integer to every element of the string, so for instance I want to add 1 so that it will become:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 1322
```

Thanks for the answers.

Mahad

Comment: yep i was trying with awk something like has been suggested:
awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' myinputfile
but the result is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line would make a line by line list

`echo "1 2 3 4 5 6" | sed  "s/ /\n/g" | awk '{print $1+1}'`

and using [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)
You can do

`echo "1 2 3 4 5 6" | sed  "s/ /\n/g" | awk '{print $1+1}' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

And, replace your my `echo ...` with `cat yourfile`

`cat yourfile | sed  "s/ /\n/g" | awk '{print $1+1}' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`

Comment: @user2710445 - If you like it, you may tag the answer ?